# not assigning value to nested model in swift

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

trying to assign value to my model object but returns nil

my models :

```
struct Request:Mappable{


    var  id:String="" //
    var  origin:Location? 

}
  mutating func mapping(map: Map) {


        id <- map["id"]//
        origin <- map["origin"] //

}


struct Location :Mappable{

    var address=Address()


    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {

        address <- map["address"]

    }


var request=Request()
request.origin?.address.province?.id = "test" // assign nil
```

Comment: Steer clear of `ObjectMapper` and look at Swift 4's `Codable` protocol instead

Comment: takes time to convert all my models to Codable. also what if I use swift 3 ?

Comment: If you're using Swift 3, I'll just wish you good luck!

Comment: As `origin` is `nil` so nothing will be assigned further. You need to make sure `origin` and `province` are not `nil`

Comment: When you create a request obj like `var request = Request()`, this variable has field `origin ` with nil value. That's why the `id` value will not be saved. You need to set `origin` firstly.

Comment: @kamran why ? at first declaration object must be nil then we could assign value at it

Comment: @G.Veronika what if I do this way let request:Request?    not working as same

Comment: Yes, so first you need to assign values to origin and province. If any of then is nil then how can you reach id?

Comment: @M0TRIX you should firstly assign value to `origin` and then to `id`
`var request = Request()` `request .origin = ...` 
Also, you should be sure `province` is not nil. You can't assign field of nil object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have `Address` and `Province` types as below,

```
struct Address {
    var province: Province?
}

struct Province {
    var id: String?
}
```

then to assign a value to province `id`, you need to setup the `request` as below,

```
var request = Request()
request.origin = Location()
request.origin?.address.province = Province()
request.origin?.address.province?.id = "test"
```

Comment: how to did you achieve to this solution ?? working perfectly.

Comment: As i mentioned in one of the comments, `origin` and `province` need to be `non-nil` to rearch `id`. As `request` is new object where `origin` and `province` are `nil`. So i initialized both before assigning the value to `id`.

Comment: request.origin = Location(). how this is working ? location is nil too